# Como capturar um objeto que teve um valor de atributo modificado

Tags: jquery

Tenho um objeto que pode ser atualizado a partir de uma interação drag-drop com um objeto grid-stack (https://github.com/troolee/gridstack.js#questions-and-answers). Dependendo da atualização do objeto (mudança de posição) um atributo dele é modificado. Como posso capturar as modificações deste objeto específico. Levando em conta somente a mudança do atributo.

Eu consigo capturar o objeto se o usuário clica em cima dele com o evento "click".

```html
$("div.container-fluid").on("click", "div.grid div#view", function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

O objeto a ser capturado está no DOM:

```html
<div data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> </div>
```

Os atributos que são modificados são: data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4". Esses atributos são alterados por uma interação drag drop do componente grid-stack.

Algumas dúvidas:
Existe algum evento que capture o clique e arraste via mouse?
Ou o próprio gridStack possui? (eu não encontrei nada na documentação).
Ou tem como monitorar mudanças (de atributos) em objetos DOM de forma automática?

Comment: `.prop('minhaProp');` - se explicares melhor juntando um exemplo posso explicar melhor também.

Comment: oi Sergio, o problema não é pegar a propriedade de um objeto. Mas, saber se o objeto sofreu alguma modificação.

Comment: Explica melhor a pergunta. Como está eu não consegui perceber que queres saber quando o objeto foi modificado e não sei ainda que tipo de modificação e qual a ação/função que o modifica.

Comment: É um objeto do DOM ou é um objeto q vc cria via codigo?
qual elemento é uma div?

Comment: É um objeto do DOM: `<div data-gs-x="0" data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4" data-gs-height="4" class="grid-stack-item ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-resizable-autohide"> </div>`. Ele pode mudar os atributos `data-gs-y="0" data-gs-width="4"` se o usuário clicar e arrastar.

Comment: @BrunoNascimento, segue um `JSFiddle` com um MutationObserve que deve resolver o seu problema: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z6xe12hb/)

Answer (score 0):

Bruno, você pode utilizar a API `MutationObserver` para capturar mutações no objeto `DOM`, dentre elas, alterações nos atributos.

No exemplo abaixo eu criei uma camada adicional chamada `AttributeObserver`, esta camada vai observar apenas alterações nos attibutos, e o callback será chamado apenas quando o novo valor for diferente do antigo.

```js
// Classe para observar mutações nos attributos de um determinado elemento.
var AttributeObserver = function (element) {
  var that = this;
  this.element = element;
  this.observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation, indice) {
      var name = mutation.attributeName;
      var event = that.attributes[mutation.attributeName];
      var value = that.element.getAttribute(name);
      if (event && mutation.oldValue != value)
        event(mutation);
    })
  });  
  this.attributes = {};
  this.observer.observe(numero, { attributes: true, attributeOldValue: true });
}

AttributeObserver.prototype.observe = function (attributeName, callback) {
  this.attributes[attributeName] = callback;
}

// Exemplo de utilização.
var numero = document.getElementById("numero");
var observer = new AttributeObserver(numero);
observer.observe("data-primo", function (mutation) {
  var log = { 
    prop: "data-primo", 
    oldValue: mutation.oldValue, 
    newValue: mutation.target.getAttribute("data-primo")
  };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(log));
});

// Alterar attributo monitorado.
window.setInterval(function () {
  var num = parseInt(numero.textContent) + 1;
  numero.dataset.primo = isPrime(num);
  numero.textContent = num;
}, 1000);

// verificar se um numero é primo
function isPrime (n)
{
  if (n < 2) 
    return false;

  var q = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n));
  for (var i = 2; i <= q; i++)
  {
    if (n % i == 0)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<span id="numero" data-primo="false">1</span>
```